# Multistore save product to wrong url

Tags: product, multistore, backend

We set up a multistore with subdomain. Our problem is when we save or update a product we have an redirect to subdomain url. But the product is saved/updated.

Hope for help :)

PS: srry for my english

Comment: Please provide expected situation atleast after which you think the problem starts, you just provide the core problem.

Comment: ok. the problem starts when we set the store url from second store to subdomain. when the second store have the same url like the main store its fine.

Comment: Any redirection in htaccess file?

Comment: nope..nothing any other idea? please :)

Comment: we've checked all rewrites over magento backend and mysql.